# removing text between "/*" and "*/" (Block Comments)

Tags: c#, wpf, streamreader

I am trying to remove block comments reading from a text file.
So all text between '/*' and '*/' should be removed. The reader reads line for line and that where the problem comes in.
This is what i have so far:

```
        StringBuilder buildString = new StringBuilder();

        using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string line;
            // reads the file line by line
            while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //replaces the line if it has "--" in it.
                line = Regex.Replace(line, @"--.*$", "");

                if (line.StartsWith("/*"))
                {
                    while ((line = readFile.ReadLine() ) != null)
                    {
                        //remove line untill the last line '*/'
                        if (line.StartsWith("*/"))
                        {
                            //Then Stop removing lines and go back to the main while.
                        } 
                    }
                }

                buildString.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

Any suggestions or help?
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the [`break` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)?

Comment: Define "the problem".   There is a buildString.AppendLine

Comment: The problem was being able to right the code out, i couldnt figure out how to go about doing it. But ive got it right. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using stack data structure will do the job.  However, you have to read character by character instead of a line.

#### Steps:

1. Don't preprocess as long as you don't encounter a `"/"`.
2. When you encounter a '/' check if the next character is a `"*"`.

   - If yes, push all data into the stack till a `"*/"` combination comes.
3. When a `"*/"` comes push to the output.

If a `"*/"` doesn't come or if a `"*/"` doesn't have a matching `"/*"`, then throw error.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regex something like

\x2F\x2A.*\x2A\x2F

https://www.google.com/search?q=q=regex+tutorial+in+c%23

the \x2F is hex for / and \x2A is hex for * the regex class accept hex codes for characters, so if you use a  multiline regex, this should allow you to select the block comments

EDIT: an example function

```
public string RemoveBlockComments(string InputString)
{
   string strRegex = @"\/\*.*|.*(\n\r)*\*\/";
   RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
   Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
   return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, "");
}
```

Comment: Wow, Hi surya. Uhm could you please explain that or refer me to a site that will help me understand whats actually going on in that line of  code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this item:

```
var Test = Regex.Replace(MyString, @"/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*([^/]|[\r\n])))*\*/", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

ref =>
https://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment